# 3D plot using three 1D arrays Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have three 1D NumPy Arrays XX, YY, and ZZ. They are organized such that ZZ[i] is the height of a hill at coordinates XX[i], YY[i]. How can I plot this using Python?

Edit:
The arrays are quite large (each contain about 3e5 data points)

Edit 2: I want a surface plot

Thanks

Comment: What sort of plot do you want? A scatter plot, a surface plot, a contour plot...?

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried so far? Are you getting errors? Did you try anything before you posted the question?

Comment: You can use `matplotlib` for [surface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html) plots. But you first need to re-organise your arrays on a regular grid. You can use [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html)

Comment: If the input is organised as a regular grid, `ax.plot_surface` with reshaped x, y and z is recommended.  If the input x and y are irregular spaced, [`ax.trisurf3d`](ax.https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/trisurf3d.html) will work.

Comment: @JohanC, thanks, `ax.trisurf3d` fixed it.